Subfigure arrangement with relatively complex combination of shapes and sizes
I have six figures, which I need to arrange like the following image:

The image sizes are provided in points, e.g. green: 622 by 350. I have found these examples

How to put 5 images with different sizes in Latex
Subfigures within minipage
Special arrangement of subfigures
Figure and two subfigures side by side using caption/subcaption

but unable to formulate the right code to replicate it. It's making it haphazard:
\begin{landscape} %linewidth: when using landscape page vs textwidth: when normal
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.666\linewidth} %((525+622)/(525+622+575))
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.454\textwidth}%\linewidth} %~(575/(525+622))
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{lightBlue}
        %\subcaption{}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.538\textwidth}%~(622/(525+622))
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{green}   %\subcaption{}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
%   \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.3612\linewidth} %(1158/(1158+575))
        \begin{subfigure}[]{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{red}
%       \subcaption{}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
%%  \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.6682\linewidth}%((525+622)/(525+622+575))
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{black}
%       \subcaption{black}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}  
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33179\linewidth}%(575/(1158+575))
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{DarkBlue1}
        %\subcaption{}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{DarkBlue2}
        %\subcaption{}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
\caption{JUBA}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

Questions:

Is it even possible or impossible with packages such as minipage and subcaption
Any other possible solutions are also welcome!


Two general suggestions. First, since there doesn't appear to be a need for captions, I can seen no reason for using figure and subfigure machinery; just use minipage environments. Second, I suggest using nested minipages: Place the three graphs on the left in minipages and the place all three into a larger minipage. Same for the three graphs on the right.

I improved my coding. Now the arrangement is right but there is a huge gap in between the two horizontal rows (3 on top and 3 at bottom) of images.

@Mico,  I'm not sure I understand. Will you kindly put an example here, maybe as an answer if the code is too big?

Please see the answer I posted. Should the height of the dark blue rectangles in the lower right maybe be 426pt instead of 423pt? For sure, if 426pt is correct, then one could use 11pt as the width for all horizontal and vertical whitespace gaps.

@Mico, egreg, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/34505/john-kormylo, thanks so much! Now the problem is all answers are good, so indecisive about which one to accept :D

(I've modified the answer to use the \resizebox device used in @egreg's parallel answer. I'm keeping the minipage-based setup, though.)

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment
\usepackage{graphicx}  % for '\resizebox' and '\includegraphics' macros

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape} 

\begin{figure}[p!]
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{minipage}{1158pt} % width of black rectangle
\includegraphics[width=525pt,height=350pt]{example-image}% 
\hspace{11pt}% 1158-(525+622)
\includegraphics[width=622pt,height=350pt]{example-image}

\vspace{11pt}% choose same amounts for vertixal and horizontal whitespace padding
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=651pt]{example-image}           
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{11pt}%
\begin{minipage}{575pt} % width of red square       
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\linewidth]{example-image}

\vspace{14pt} % (350+651+11)-(575+423) % can't use '11pt'
\includegraphics[width=282pt,height=423pt]{example-image}% 
\hspace{11pt}% 575-2*282
\includegraphics[width=282pt,height=423pt]{example-image}% 
\end{minipage}}

\caption{JUBA}
\end{figure}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}


all useful answers, but accepting this for being the first.

No minipages nor complicated calculations.
Of course the images won't fit the text width, but we can just resize the whole block.
I used width and height to reproduce the dimensions, but you likely just want width.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  %%% first column
  \begin{tabular}{c}
  \includegraphics[width=525pt,height=350pt]{example-image}%
  \hspace{11pt}% 1158-525-622
  \includegraphics[width=622pt,height=350pt]{example-image}
  \\\noalign{\vspace{12pt}}% 350+651+12=1013
  \includegraphics[width=1158pt,height=651pt]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}%
  %%% space in between
  \hspace{11pt}%
  %%% second column
  \begin{tabular}{c}
  \includegraphics[width=575pt,height=575pt]{example-image}
  \\\noalign{\vspace{15pt}}% 575+423+15=1013
  \includegraphics[width=282pt,height=423pt]{example-image}%
  \hspace{11pt}% 575-282-282
  \includegraphics[width=282pt,height=423pt]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}%
}

\end{figure}

\end{document}



+1. If the figure were rendered in a landscape environment (provided by the pdflscape package), it would be advisable to replace \resizebox{\textwidth} with \resizebox{\linewidth}.

For something this complicated, I would use a tikzicture.  Note that inner sep=3pt creates a 6pt gap between nodes.  I had to tweak a couple of images to get them to fit.
I used standalone class to avoid worrying about the page size.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}% no figures in standalone
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=3pt, outer sep=0pt}]
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (1734pt,-1003pt);% remove excess
    \node[below right] at (-3pt,3pt) (A) {\includegraphics[width=525pt,height=350pt]{example-image}};
    \node[below right] at (A.north east) (B) {\includegraphics[width=622pt,height=350pt]{example-image}};
    \node[below right] at (B.north east) (C) {\includegraphics[width=575pt,height=575pt]{example-image}};
    \node[below right] at (A.south west) (D) {\includegraphics[width=1153pt,height=651pt]{example-image}};
    \node[below right] at (C.south west) (E) {\includegraphics[width=283pt,height=423pt]{example-image}};
    \node[below left] at (C.south east) (F) {\includegraphics[width=283pt,height=423pt]{example-image}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}



thanks for adding this! I'm relatively new to tikzpicture but this looks very clean and comprehensible for new users!

this works find except the total figure is overflowing the page (whether vertical or landscape). How do I scale it?

You can use the scale option of tikzpicture, or \resizebox (graphicx package).  You may also need \noindent.
